# Looping Through a column and append value to list based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe and a list of unique invoice numbers. I want to loop through the dateframe and check to see if the invoice number in that row is in my list. If so, then assign a value (either 1 or 0) to a column I have just created. I have tried .iterrows and some other methods and I probably messed up the syntax or something. See below for the setup and any guidance is appreciated.

```
InvoiceNo  StockCode ....... UnitPrice CustomerID NEWCOLUMN
536365      85123A            2.55       17850    
536366      22633             1.85       17850
536372      84879             1.69       13047
```

I was trying something like this and not getting anywhere:

```
new_list = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df[i, 'InvoiceNo'] in comparison_list:
         df[i, 'NEWCOLUMN'] = 0
    else:
         df[i, 'NEWCOLUMN'] = 1
```

Any insight is appreciated!
** Python 3.9.13
** Pandas 1.4.4

Answer (score 2):

First create the new column an assign a default value

```py
df["NEWCOLUMN"] = 0
```

Create a function that verifies if some invoice code is in the comparison_list

```py
def verify(invoice_code):
    if invoice_code in comparison_list:
       return 1 
    else:
       return 0
```

(it is not necessary to do a for loop because pandas will call that function for every row).

Then you can call

```py
df["NEWCOLUMN"] = df["InvoiceNo"].apply(verify)
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately whatever the default value is for the NEWCOLUMN doesn't change after running that function. I assigned it with a default value of 1 and every row has a value of 1 when I know roughly half should be 0's.

Comment: it is because the type of variable. InvoiceNo in the df it's an int but in comparison list the codes are strings or ints?

Comment: This does work, I had made an error and was checking the wrong column, lol, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do it with a for loop, you could try the following steps:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['InvoiceNo'] in comparasion_list:
        df.loc[i, 'NEWCOLUMN'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'NEWCOLUMN'] = 0
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I could use .iterrrows() but just couldn't get the syntax right. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if values are in the list with the following code. To convert boolean values to numbers use "astype" method.

```
df['NEWCOLUMN'] = df['InvoiceNo'].isin(new_list).astype(int)
```